# Problema com dotnet-ef database update no linux

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linux, dotnet-cli

Estou com um problema no dotnet entity framework. Após executar o dotnet-ef migrations add CriarUmaTabela que ocorre tudo bem, em seguida tento executar o comando dotnet-ef database update e recebo o seguinte erro:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid
```

A connectionStrings ficou assim:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=Agenda; Integrated Security=True"
```

}

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

Embora pareça uma pergunta trivial, o detalhe é que a segurança integrada não funcionará no Linux (pelo menos sem configuração, a autenticação Kerberos é suportada), porque está relacionada à autorização do Active Directory / NTML.

Portanto, use a string de conexão de autorização de nome de usuário padrão.
Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost; Database=Agenda; User Id=sa; Password=SuaSenha"
  }
```

Tenha certeza também de que em outro terminal esteja com uma instância do SQL Server aberta. Pode saber também os dados dela com o comando:

```
SELECT @@servername, @@servicename;
GO
```

Se te ajudei, dá um grau na minha resposta. Abraços.